# [Android Studio]Gradle seems like wrong encoded

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

[image]

- When I compile with errors, Code Analysis will show like the picture.
- I do think it gives me the error description.
- How can I get the right Gradle description?

Comment: We'll need to see your build script and what task you are executing. Also what IDE are you using?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko I'm really sorry! I have forgot it! Really, really sorry! This will come out when I debug with Android Studio.

Comment: Do you have an example project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko Any project can reproduce the issue as long as it has     compiling error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following steps:

**File->settings...->Editor->Colors&Fonts->Font** 

Click **Save As**, and write a name;

Uncheck **Show only monospaced fonts**, find **Microsoft YaHei** UI in the list of **Available fonts** and set it be **Selected fonts**

Click OK